# how to serve an arbitrary static website with Sails js?

Tags: sails.js

I created a symlink to the pages in the /assets folder called /myapp.
Then tried to access via http://192.168.20.20:1337/myapp.
I was able to access index.html, but not able to access any of the relative content like css & js files.

What's the correct way to do this and allow access to all the content?
Is there a way to just point a route to an arbitrary directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
// config/http.js

module.exports.http = {
    customMiddleware: function (app) {
        var express = require('express');
        app.use('/myapp', express.static('/var/www/mysite'));
    }
...
```